# How to hide any html element by using another class in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How can I hide an element below **hide_below_element** selector using Javascript.

```
<div class"hide_below_element">asdfasdfasd</div>
<div><a> the element for hiding form hide_below_element selector</a> </div> 
<div><a>Another information no need to hide </a> </div>
```

Thanks for your supported us.

Comment: It's unclear exactly what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: Why not put below elements inside "hide_below_element" div instead?

Comment: No I can't input and if like that it easy but I want to disable as above case because some code i can't edit and insert any selector

Comment: Have you considered using jQuery.hide() to do this?

Comment: @JeffPrince
Yes if possible to do with Jquery is good

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not quite sure what you want to accomplish, but what about this :

```
$('.hide_below_element').next().hide();
```